# Mongoose virtual with multiple foreignFields

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a Schema `Events` which has a key `creator` which is a reference to the creator and a key `musicians` which is an array with the musicians.

A Musician can create `Events` or participate as a musician. I want to create a virtual property named `events` to the musician which will contain all the events that the musician has created and the events that participates.

I tried this:

```
MusicianSchema.virtual('events', {
    ref: 'Events',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: ['creator, musicians'],
    justOne: false,
});
```

but this returns an empty array. Is there any way to make it work, or mongoose doesn't have this feature (yet)?

*EDIT*

This is the Event Schema:

```
const eventSchema = {
    title: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    startDate: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    endDate: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    picture: {
        type: String,
        get: getPicture,
    },
    location: {
        type: [Number],
        index: '2dsphere',
        get: getLocation
    },
    creator: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        refPath: 'creatorType'
    },
    musicians: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Musician'
    }],
    creatorType: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: ['Musician', 'Entity']
    }
};
```

And the Musicians Schema:

```
const musiciansSchema = {
    name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    picture: {
        type: String,
        get: getPicture,
    },
    description: String,
    type: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: ['Band', 'Artist'],
    },
};
```

Comment: Add other schema too

Comment: @ŞivāSankĂr I added the events and the musician schemes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mongoose virtual with multiple `foreignField` feature is not available at the moment, Suggestion for new feature has already requested on [GitHub](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6608),

For now you need to use separate virtual/populate

```
MusicianSchema.virtual('creatorEvents', {
    ref: 'Events',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'creator',
    justOne: false,
});

MusicianSchema.virtual('musiciansEvents', {
    ref: 'Events',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'musicians',
    justOne: false,
});
```

Comment: Yes I saw this thread in Github. Anyway, I guess I have to wait. Thank you!

Comment: I believe this solution does not work, I have tried myself, with no success.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar situation during development and what I did was to replicate the same code twice but with different virtual names and  it works perfectly.

In your case:

​MusicianSchema​.​virtual​(​'createdEvents'​,​ ​{​
    ​ref​: ​'Events'​,​
    ​localField​: ​'_id'​,​
    ​foreignField​: ​'creator'​,​
    ​justOne​: ​false​,​
​}​)​;​

​MusicianSchema​.​virtual​(​'musicianEvents'​,​ ​{​
    ​ref​: ​'Events'​,​
    ​localField​: ​'_id'​,​
    ​foreignField​: ​'musician​,​
    ​justOne​: ​false​,​
​}​)​;​